# Detect Excel Dialog Boxes from Python

Tags: python, excel, windows, com, dialog

I'm trying to automate a lot of boring Excel work using Python Jupyter notebooks. Thankfully, it's easy to get Python and Excel to interact using `win32com`, so most of the work can be automated. However, one issue I've been running into is that Excel likes to use a lot of dialog boxes.
Sometimes even macros I need to run require input through a dialog box. When these appear repeatedly in a for loop, I have to be present to click "No" on the dialog box for each iteration, which is far from ideal.

Is there some way to get Python to interact with the dialog box when it appears? I could use PyAutoGUI to scan the screen, but the issue is that sometimes the dialog box appears behind other windows that are open, so it may not detect it; not to mention, it would have to be constantly scanning, and given the dialog box doesn't appear until the macro has already been running for a couple minutes, it would have to be checking quite frequently.

I could also use autohotkey, as autohotkey can detect when a dialog box appears and automatically send it input (even if it isn't in focus) by using `WinWait` and `ControlSend`, but it would be nice if there was a fully native Python solution to this problem.

Any suggestions?